# C# encoding in DES encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, encoding, cryptography

My main method runs without errors, but the decrypted message is not correct.  I'm almost certain I'm not properly encoding, but I can't nail down the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my first post, so if I've inadvertently broken a rule or not adhered to a guideline, please let me know.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string unencryptedString = "cat";
    string encryptedString;
    string decryptedString;

    string password = "password";

    System.Console.WriteLine("Unencrypted String: " + unencryptedString);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Password: " + password);

    encryptedString = StandardEncryptor.Encrypt(unencryptedString, password);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Encrypted String: " + encryptedString);

    decryptedString = StandardEncryptor.Decrypt(encryptedString, password);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Decrypted String: " + decryptedString);

    System.Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string Encrypt(string message, string password)
{
    // Encode message and password
    byte[] messageBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    byte[] passwordBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

    // Set encryption settings -- Use password for both key and init. vector
    DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(passwordBytes, passwordBytes);
    CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

    // Set up streams and encrypt
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, transform, mode);
    cryptoStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // Read the encrypted message from the memory stream
    byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Position = 0;
    memStream.Read(encryptedMessageBytes, 0, encryptedMessageBytes.Length);

    // Encode the encrypted message as base64 string
    string encryptedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedMessageBytes);

    return encryptedMessage; 
}

public static string Decrypt(string encryptedMessage, string password)
{
    // Convert encrypted message and password to bytes
    byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedMessage);
    byte[] passwordBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

    // Set encryption settings -- Use password for both key and init. vector
    DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateDecryptor(passwordBytes, passwordBytes);
    CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

    // Set up streams and decrypt
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, transform, mode);
    cryptoStream.Write(encryptedMessageBytes, 0, encryptedMessageBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // Read decrypted message from memory stream
    byte[] decryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Position = 0;
    memStream.Read(decryptedMessageBytes, 0, decryptedMessageBytes.Length);

    // Encode deencrypted binary data to base64 string
    string message = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedMessageBytes);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: After a quick look at your code I can't see the problem you describe, but I'd recommend that you don't use the password as the initialisation vector. The IV must be different for every encrypted message, otherwise your crypto will be vulnerable to statistical analysis. It's OK to create a random IV and append (or prepend) it to the ciphertext. The IV is not secret but it must be single-use.

Comment: Furthermore, DES is broken. I'd suggest at least 3DES, or ideally AES for block encryption. AES is Officially Not Broken Yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the problem on the second to last line?

```
string message = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedMessageBytes);
```

I may be off track here but I don't think you intended to convert the string bytes back to base64. Do you just need to convert the bytes back to a string?

```
string message = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.FromBytes(decryptedMessageBytes);
```

Comment: That was definitely the problem-Thanks!

Comment: I did not find the FromBytes method. Used GetString instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in Decrypt:

```
// Encode deencrypted binary data to base64 string
string message = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedMessageBytes);
```

I don't think you want to do this to the decrypted data. The decrypted bytes are already ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem using just this

```
//Encode deencrypted binary data to base64 string
string message = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedMessageBytes);
```